# How to fix error "Bone Heat Weighting: failed to find solution for one or more bones" in low-poly mesh

Tags: mesh, rigging, armature, bones

I'm currently working on rigging my first character mesh for a simple project. However, I'm receiving the aforementioned error every time I try to parent with automatic weights. I've checked various other posts and tried a few methods to fix it but nothing has worked thus far:

- Confirmed there was no non-manifold geometry
- Removed all duplicate vertices
- Recalculated vertex normals
- Scaled up my model (Even though I *highly doubt* this is the issue; see photo)

I'm not sure what I could be missing here. My guess is I over-complicated something on the mesh itself, but it's a very low-poly character so I'm not sure what I could be missing.

I've also included the file. It should be less than a MB. [Link to the model file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1lFlHnue_TE0QvTwvNKUU-XCdyuqW4l_O/view?usp=sharing)
Any help with this would be greatly appreciated :)

[image: Low-Poly Ninja model]

Comment: Any particular reason why you have two mirror modifiers on the same object?

Comment: Not particularly. I noticed that I had two when I was trying to find solutions, but I didn't see a difference between having two/removing one, so I didn't mess with it. I'm very new to this, so I just went the safe route.

Comment: Ok. Go into Edit mode with the model selected. In vertex mode, select All (A key), then press 'M' > Merge by distance. - You still had 57 overlapping vertices which were preventing the armature parenting correctly. The model parented and worked fine after I did that. In fact it still parented ok with the second mirror modifier, but it's probably a good idea to delete that one anyway to prevent confusion later.

Comment: Wow, I don't know how I didn't catch that the first time. I swear I tried merging by distance before, but maybe I accidentally did edges twice. Regardless, thank you so much!

Comment: Going to start a close vote on this since duplicate vertices are mentioned in the highest voted "related" question.  Can confirm that duplicate vertices (which make zero area faces, without defined normals) are the issue.